# How can I suppress .NET CLI's welcome message on first run?

Tags: dotnet-cli

I am using .NET CLI in an Azure DevOps pipeline, and I am using PowerShell to parse its output. The first command I run is `dotnet nuget locals global-packages --list`.

The output when you run this the first time is this:

```
Welcome to .NET 6.0!
---------------------
SDK Version: 6.0.101

Telemetry
---------
The .NET tools collect usage data in order to help us improve your experience. It is collected by Microsoft and shared with the community. You can opt-out of telemetry by setting the DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT environment variable to '1' or 'true' using your favorite shell.

Read more about .NET CLI Tools telemetry: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-telemetry

----------------
Installed an ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate.
To trust the certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust' (Windows and macOS only).
Learn about HTTPS: https://aka.ms/dotnet-https
----------------
Write your first app: https://aka.ms/dotnet-hello-world
Find out what's new: https://aka.ms/dotnet-whats-new
Explore documentation: https://aka.ms/dotnet-docs
Report issues and find source on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/core
Use 'dotnet --help' to see available commands or visit: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
global-packages: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\
```

As you can see, there is a whole story about telemetry, certificates, and some links, followed by the simple output that I need to parse. Running it again just outputs that last line:

```
global-packages: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\
```

I need to suppress this output, because it makes automation more difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this post](https://travis-ci.community/t/possible-disabling-of-welcome-message-in-net-core-3-1-300/8772), .NET Core 3.1 added an environment variable called `DOTNET_NOLOGO`, which, when set (to 1? to anything?) will suppress the welcome message.

This, much more [recent post](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/10411) confirms it's still relevant.

Can you add this env variable to your CI pipeline environment?

Comment: it worked for me when setting it to `true`, e.g. `export DOTNET_NOLOGO=true`